# Как увеличить размер экрана виртуальной машины VMWare в Windows 10?

Tags: vmware

Не могу добиться постоянного полноэкранного режима в виртуальной машине VMWare Workstation в системе Windows 10. На VMWare стоит CentOS 7. Когда включаю виртуальную машину и логинюсь, приходится сначала сворачивать окно виртуальной машины, потом разворачивать и щелкать по маленькому экрану двойным щелчком мыши. Тогда экран становится развернутым. Но такие танцы с бубном проводить каждый раз не вариант... Что пробовал.

1. Пытался переустановить VMWare Tools командой /usr/bin/vmware-uninstall-tools.pl - пишет command not found.
2. Запускал от имени sudo команду regedit - тоже command not found.
   Подскажите пожалуйста в правильном ли направлении копаю?